# How to show all warnings of C++ in Qt 4.8 Issues Tab?

Tags: c++, qt, g++, gcc-warning

In my application inside Qt, when I open some CPP file, in some I see warnings like the one I describe below:

- warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'X'
- warning: use of old-style cast
- warning: adding 'int' to a string does not append to the string

And many others that I do not need to describe.

What I really wanted was for all these errors / alerts to be displayed in the Qt Issues tab when the application compilation is performed, but this does not happen.

Why are they not presented and is there any way to present them?

I tried to use the flags below, but none had the effect I wanted:

```
CONFIG += warn_on
CONFIG += exceptions

QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON = -w -Wall -Wextra
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -w -Wall -Wextra

CFLAGS += -Wall
CXXFLAGS += -Wall

QMAKE_LFLAGS += thread
QMAKE_LFLAGS += exceptions
```

I just found here in stackoverflow questions to suppress the warnings.

This would make it much easier to improve the quality of the software, because the software I'm working on is legacy and I have no vision of these warnings unless I open file by file.

Comment: Qt is a software framework.  Qt Creator is an editor (IDE) that comes with Qt.  I'm pretty sure you mean Qt Creator.  Since Qt Creator is just an application, you can update without changing the version of Qt you are running.  Newer versions are much better at displaying code issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings you see **inside** the editor are from the Clang code model plugin of Qt Creator.
You can try changing to compiling using Clang instead of GCC/MSVC and it should hopefully give you the same warnings also during compilation.

See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-tool-chains.html) help page for more information on adding compilers.

---

**Edit:** You can also trigger a manual analysis, which will display the code issues in the "Issues" pane.

To do this, open up the "Analyze" menu in the menu bar, and select "Clang-Tidy and Clazy..."

In the dialog that appears, select all files that you want to analyze, and also select "Custom Settings" from the topmost drop down, followed by "Clang-only checks for almost everything [built-in]" from the second drop down.

That option is equivalent to the default option for the Clang code model plugin, and should make the analyze output show the same issues as the inline annotations.

When you are ready, simply click "Analyze" to start and then wait until it's all complete.

See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-tools.html) page for even more detailed information on how to run and configure static code analysis from Qt Creator.

Comment: Problem now is that I use Poky for compilation for ARM and I do not have Clang on it, so there appeared several errors and not the warnings I was expecting.

Comment: @msribeir What you could do is to run the static code analyzis manually. Just go to "Analyze" in the menu bar, and select "Clang-Tidy and Clazy". Then press "Analyze" in the dialog that comes up. That way you will force an analyzation of all files, and the result will be displayed in the "Issues" pane as requested. I will update my answer with this information.